# Redux store not registering that state has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

When my reducer runs, the store does change to the new value, but the redux devtools shows that the store was always at the new value and never the old value. Am I mutating state in the `editSnippetReducerFunction` reducer or something?

```
const addSnippetReducerFunction = (state: any, action): any => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    snippets: [
      ...state.snippets,
      {
        text: action.payload.text,
        id: action.payload.id
      }
    ]
  })
}

const editSnippetReducerFunction = (state: any, action): any => {
  const newSnippets = state.snippets.map(snippet => {
      if (snippet.id === action.payload.id) {
          snippet.text = action.payload.text
          return snippet
      } else {
          return snippet
      }
  })
  return { snippets: newSnippets, ...state}
}

const removeSnippetReducerFunction = (state: any, action): any => {
  const newSnippets = state.snippets.filter(snippet => snippet.id !== action.payload.id)
  return { snippets: newSnippets, history: [] }
}

export const rootReducer: any = createReducer(initialState, {
  ADD_SNIPPET: addSnippetReducerFunction,
  EDIT_SNIPPET: editSnippetReducerFunction,
  REMOVE_SNIPPET: removeSnippetReducerFunction
})
```

The action is dispatched with the correct details. It is only the `editSnippetReducerFunction` reducer function that has this issue, The other reducers shown above do work correctly.

EDIT: It actually works if I stop using react-redux `connect` on the component and I move the `action` to the parent component which is `connect`ed and working.

The component that doesn't work when `connect`ed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon'
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import MoreHorizIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz'
import CodeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Code'
import { styles } from './snippet.style.js'
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'
import { removeSnippet } from '../app/action'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import type { Dispatch } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): any => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      removeSnippet: removeSnippet
    },
    dispatch
  )
}

class SnippetComponent extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      anchorEl: undefined
    }
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget })
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null })
  }

  handleRemove = () => {
    this.props.removeSnippet({snippetId: this.props.snippet.id})
  }
  render = () => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        button
        onClick={() => this.props.onSnippetClick(this.props.snippet)}
        className={this.props.classes.listItem}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <CodeIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
          style={{
            marginRight: '100px',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
          }}
          primary={this.props.snippet.text}
        />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <Button
            variant="fab"
            color="primary"
            aria-owns={this.state.anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : null}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            className={this.props.classes.iconHover}
            style={{
              marginRight: '50px',
              boxShadow: 'none',
              color: 'white'
            }}
            aria-label="Add">
            <MoreHorizIcon />
          </Button>
          <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(this.state.anchorEl)}
            onClose={this.handleClose}>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove Snippet</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Share</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }
}

SnippetComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  snippet: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  addToCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const Snippet = withStyles(styles)(
  connect(
    undefined,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(SnippetComponent)
)

export default withStyles(styles)(Snippet)
```

The parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import brace from 'brace'
import AceEditor from 'react-ace'
import 'brace/mode/javascript'
import 'brace/theme/gruvbox'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add'
import { bindActionCreators, createStore } from 'redux'
import type { Dispatch } from 'redux'
import { addSnippet, editSnippet, removeSnippet } from './action'
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import Snippet from '../snippet/Snippet'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import { rootReducer } from './app.reducer.js'
import type { Props, AppState } from './app.model.js'
import { appHeaderHeight } from './app.style.js'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { styles } from './app.style.js'
import Header from '../header/Header'
import ConfirmDialog from '../confirm/ConfirmDialog'

// and so is this. proptypes needs it in initial state and also mapstatetoprops
const mapStateToProps = (
  state: any,
  ownProps: { buttonColour: string }
): any => ({
  snippets: state.snippets,
  history: state.history,
  buttonColour: ownProps.buttonColour
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): any => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      addSnippet: addSnippet,
      editSnippet: editSnippet
    },
    dispatch
  )
}

class AppComponent extends Component<Props, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      editor: React.createRef(),
      saveButtonDisabled: true,
      editorValue: '',
      open: false,
      lastClickedSnippet: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.updateWindowDimensions()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions)
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions)
  }

  updateWindowDimensions = () => {
    this.setState({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    })
  }

  onEditorChange = editorValue => {
    if (editorValue.length > 5) {
      this.setState({ saveButtonDisabled: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ saveButtonDisabled: true })
    }
    this.setState({ editorValue: editorValue })
  }

  onSaveButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({ saveButtonDisabled: true })
    if (this.state.lastClickedSnippet) {
      this.props.editSnippet({
        snippetId: this.state.lastClickedSnippet.id,
        snippetText: this.state.editorValue
      })
      this.setState({ lastClickedSnippet: undefined })
    } else {
      this.props.addSnippet({
        text: this.state.editor.current.editor.getValue()
      })
    }
    this.setState({ editorValue: '' })
  }

  onSnippetClick = (snippet: Snippet) => {
    this.setState({ lastClickedSnippet: snippet })
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }

  onDialogClose = value => {
    this.setState({ value, open: false })
  }  

  handleOk = () => {
    this.setState({ editorValue: this.state.lastClickedSnippet.text })
    this.onDialogClose(this.state.value)
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ lastClickedSnippet: undefined })
    this.onDialogClose(this.state.value)
  };

  render = () => {
    let allSnippets = []
    if (this.props.snippets) {
      allSnippets = this.props.snippets.map(snippet => (
        <Snippet
          snippet={snippet}
          key={snippet.id}
          onSnippetClick={this.onSnippetClick}
          editSnippet={this.props.editSnippet}
        />
      ))
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ConfirmDialog
          handleOk={this.handleOk}
          handleCancel={this.handleCancel}
          open={this.state.open}
          onDialogClose={this.onDialogClose}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <Header />
        <div
          className={this.props.classes.bodyContainer}
          style={{ height: this.state.height - appHeaderHeight - 70 }}>
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={0}
            alignItems={'flex-start'}
            direction={'row'}
            justify={'flex-start'}>
            <Grid
              item
              sm={12}
              md={6}
              className={this.props.classes.leftGrid}
              style={{ height: this.state.height - appHeaderHeight - 70 }}>
              <Button
                className={this.props.classes.saveButton}
                variant="fab"
                color="secondary"
                aria-label="Add"
                disabled={this.state.saveButtonDisabled}
                onClick={this.onSaveButtonClick}>
                <AddIcon />
              </Button>
              <AceEditor
                mode="javascript"
                theme="gruvbox"
                width="100%"
                value={this.state.editorValue}
                onChange={this.onEditorChange}
                height={this.state.height - appHeaderHeight - 70}
                name="editor"
                editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
                ref={this.state.editor}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              sm={12}
              md={6}
              className={this.props.classes.rightGrid}
              style={{ height: this.state.height - appHeaderHeight - 70 }}>
              <List component="nav" className={this.props.classes.navList} />
              {allSnippets}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const App = withStyles(styles)(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(AppComponent)
)

AppComponent.propTypes = {
  snippets: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.array,
  addSnippet: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools())

const SnippetApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)

export default SnippetApp
```

Comment: I have updated my answer... I could also explain why with the change that you have made things *seem* to work, but IMHO that should be a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I mutating state in the `editSnippetReducerFunction` reducer or something?

Yes, you are. You are mutating the snipped that you want to update.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
const editSnippetReducerFunction = (state: any, action): any => ({
  ...state,
  snippets: state.snippets.map(snippet =>
    snippet.id === action.payload.id
      ? {...snipped, text: action.payload.text}
      : snipped
  )),
});
```

Also, notice that this:

```
return {snippets: newSnippets, ...state}
```

Is not the same as this:

```
return {...state, snippets: newSnippets}
```

With first one, if `state` has a property named `snippets` that property will be used, instead of your `newSnippets`. With the second one, on the other hand, the `snippets` property will be updated with the `newSnippets`.

Basically, the first one is sugar for:

```
return Object.assign({}, {snippets: newSnippets}, state);
```

While the second one is the equivalent of:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {snippets: newSnippets});
```

In any event, the implementation of `editSnippetReducerFunction` that I'm suggesting addresses the 2 different problems that you had with your original implementation.